# Hi, what is the meaning of what is written on the shirt?

Tags: translation

[image]

Hi, 
I was wondering what's the meaning of what's written on the shirt?

Answer (score 2):

“海纳百川”

Literarily it means "all rivers run into sea".

In practice, it can be used to describe a person(or something else) with an open mind and tolerant heart.

You can use "海纳百川" as an adjective,

e.g.,

It is our own example as diverse and tolerant societies that welcome the contributions of all people, including those of all faiths.

In this sentence, "our societies" can be described as "海纳百川"

Answer (score 1):

海纳百川
[名]
all rivers run into sea;